# Optimize SQL Server trigger using insert and update

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I'm new to SQL Server and I want to know if my code is optimized.

My code lets me create a history table with new old and new data

```
-- ================================================
-- Template generated from Template Explorer using:
-- Create Trigger (New Menu).SQL
--
-- Use the Specify Values for Template Parameters 
-- command (Ctrl-Shift-M) to fill in the parameter 
-- values below.
--
-- See additional Create Trigger templates for more
-- examples of different Trigger statements.
--
-- This block of comments will not be included in
-- the definition of the function.
-- ================================================


 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    -- =============================================
    -- Author:      <Author,,Name>
    -- Create date: <Create Date,,>
    -- Description: <Description,,>
    -- =============================================
    CREATE TRIGGER  siniste_update_history_trigger on sinistre  AFTER UPDATE
    AS 
    BEGIN SELECT * FROM sinistre_history
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sinistre_history WHERE id = sinistre_history.id)
            UPDATE sinistre_history
            -- Update statements for trigger here
                SET old_statut = S.statut, old_statut_initial = S.statut_initial, new_statut = INS.statut, new_statut_initial = Ins.statut_initial, date = getdate()
                from inserted INS
                INNER JOIN sinistre S ON S.id = INS.id
        ELSE
            insert into sinistre_history (ID, old_statut_initial, new_statut_initial, old_statut, new_statut,DATE)
            select S.id,S.statut_initial,S.statut,INS.statut_initial,INS.statut, getdate()
            from inserted INS
            INNER JOIN sinistre S ON S.id = INS.id
    END
    GO
```

Comment: Unfortunately this site is not a code review site, this is a problem solving site. Unless you have an actual problem we don't have an answer.

Comment: Read this line - `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sinistre_history WHERE id = sinistre_history.id)` again. Realise that there's only one table in scope and so that bare `id` can only be the same column as `sinistre_history.id`.

Comment: Why are you selecting the *entirety* of the data from your table `sinistre_history` at the start of your `TRIGGER`? Returning result sets from a `TRIGGER` is deprecated and should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: Bear in mind also that `inserted` may have multiple rows, so you need a `merge` or upsert, not an `if exists`